# Stanford.NLP.NER Nuget: Does this pass data to a service or is all processing local on your devbox

Tags: stanford-nlp

I need to run NER on sensitive data and would like to know, if using Stanford.NLP.NER Nuget Package on my devbox, the text is sent to a service outside of my corp. net or if the data is processed locally on my machine.

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Microsoft NuGet or what you're using in particular, but in general you can absolutely run Stanford NER strictly on your local machine. One you can just run the pipeline and this will just launch a Java process on your local machine and use resources on your local machine. You can also launch a server which is entirely encapsulated on your local machine and once again is only using resources on the local machine.

If someone has made this available via NuGet, I would hope it was just wrapping the local process. If you could let me know more details about how you are accessing Stanford NER I can provide more insight.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The instructions for use of the Nuget package are on https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/. According to the nuget page, Stanford.NLP.NER is by the Stanford Natural Language Processing Group. Not sure if that's an official Stanford entity,

Comment: Stanford officially releases Java software. But we don't release anything with Microsoft, such as .NET versions, so I don't fully know how that works. My cursory examination of Sergey's project suggests it should just be running the Java code though (via a Java VM on top of a .NET VM), so what I said should still apply I would think. But we don't support third party extensions such as STANFORD.NLP.NER. If you run it on a laptop cut off from the internet I would expect it to work though, so that test should tell you it's not seeking external resources on the internet.